# Defining a finite set of instances of a class to check against

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, enum

I have a `Type` class that will have many instances. I get the instances from a web service. The `Type` class has a `code` instance field that uniquely ids an instance:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Type {

 private String code;

}
```

Ten of these instances identify a special type. I have several places where I need to check if a `Type` is one of these special types:

```
aType.equals(new Type("specialType1")) || aType.equals(new Type("specialType2")) ||...
```

In other places, I need to find where aType is not a special type. To centralize these specialized types and the check, I put it in the `Type` class as follows:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Type {
 
  private static final List<Type> specialTypes = Arrays.asList(new Type("specialType1"),...);
  private String code;

  public boolean isSpecialType() {
    return specialTypes.contains(this);
  }
}
```

Should specialTypes and the logic to compare a type to special types be in the `Type` class? Or would this type of logic be better in a service class? Should the special types be defined as enums?

**Update**

`Type` instances are created via use of open feign:

```
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;

@FeignClient(name="type-service")
public interface TypeClient {

   @GetMapping("/type")
   List<Type> getTypes();
}
```

Comment: Why are subclasses not an option?

Comment: It could be. Open feign is creating the `Type` instances. (I updated the OP.) I'm not sure how feign would know to create a `Type` instance versus a `SpecialType extends Type` instance.

Comment: (suggestion), If the special thing is a type-level, then have a empty interface, let say `SpecialType`, and simply implement it by those special types, later check as `if(obj instanceOf SpecialType)`.
Not sure what's this feign, but it comes with a good API, it would provide some creation API to allow you customize(take-control) object instancing.

Comment: You could manage the preloaded types in a `Set<String>` because you need uniqueness for the strings.

Comment: @911992 & @Mark Bluemel - Feign actually delegates to Jackson for deserialization.I didn't realize this until I did some research. So, it's actually Jackson that is creating the instances of `Type`. Jackson does support deserialization into subclasses. So, subclassing is an option.

Comment: @Miguel Avila - A set of strings makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, as "being special" is obviously an attribute of your `Type` class, the check should go into the `Type` class, as you did, therefore always choose:

```
public class Type {
    ...
    public boolean isSpecial() {...}
}
```

over

```
aType.equals(new Type("specialType1")) || aType.equals(new Type("specialType2")) ||...
```

Regarding the implementation: I'm not too fond of creating a static collection to compare to. First of all, you search *every time*, then you use a relatively heavyweight `equals` method, which seems somewhat exaggerated to me, if the only distinction is a string passed in the constructor.

Personally, I'd use the underlying strings as a constant and determint the `special` flag in the constructor:

```
public class Type {
    private static final List<String> SPECIAL_CODES = Arrays.asList("this", "that", "whatever");
    private final String code;
    private final boolean special;

    public Type(String code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.special = SPECIAL_CODES.contains(code);
    }

    public boolean isSpecial() {
        return special;
    }
}
```

(Note that this change will *not* make a difference in runtime in real life, unless you check `isSpecial()` in a tight loop. It is more of a gut-feeling of being somewhat clearer.)

Comment: Thank you for your insights. This is very helpful. How would you compare this solution to having  `SpecialType extends Type`?

Comment: I'd only go for inheritance, if you have a real extension of functionality, but never as a pure marker.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, the special types have **no** additional functionality (i.e. no extension of behavior, no additional fields). So it would be purely as a marker.